# regex check for last character

Tags: regex, double

Here's my problem: I need to prevent spaces at the start (check), in the end and spaces followed by a space (check). Read stuff about negative lookaheads and linking with logical operators but I don't get it workin' - that's my code so far (works but doesn't cover all my needs):

```
if (!/^[^ ](?!.*[ ]{2})([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,20})/.test(name.val())) {
```

someone can help me to finish the line?

thanks in advance! fabio

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\s` and `\S` to match whitespace and non-whitespace.

Try something like this:

```
if (!/^\S+(?!\s{2})([\w\s]{3,20})\S+$/.test(name.val())) {
```

`\w\s` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and all whitespace, so if you don't want that underscore being matched, use `[a-z\d\s]` and make your regex case-insensitive (`/asd/i.test()`)